# When updating an app in the appstore, automatic data download?

Tags: android

My question is, I have to update an app that's on the appstore when they download the update will all the data also be downloaded automatically or not, my app is a calendar with events and a recyclerView with there events and the update is to update the calendar range from last year to this year `(2019/01/01 - 2020/01/30) => (2020/01/01 - 2021/01/30)` but doing this also means I need to download the calendar events again.

My download function is in the MainActivity.java and it downloads a json from online.

Is there a way to force this download when the person updates the app?

EDIT: This is the section of code that changes in this update, the widget in this case is this [dependency](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview)

```
widget.state().edit()
    .setMinimumDate(CalendarDay.from(2020, 1, 1))
    .setMaximumDate(CalendarDay.from(2021, 1, 31))
    .commit();
```

Comment: if you have updated your previous code, then yes it will be updated automatically when the app is updated.

Comment: The thing is I only update the range and nothing else on these lines 
```
 widget.state().edit()
                .setMinimumDate(CalendarDay.from(2020, 1, 1))
                .setMaximumDate(CalendarDay.from(2021, 1, 31))
                .commit();
```

Comment: yes then it should be updated when app is updated.

Answer (score 0):

This also has sdk versions dependencies as per https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup, but generally speaking two possibilities exist:

1. Your previous app is already installed and used on the device
2. This is clean install on new device of user who was using your app on other device

All the cached data for p1 will be there for your scenario.

P2 depends on your manifest configuration and if device does backups: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#allowbackup

If you application manifest says allowBackups true and device was configured/able to backup previous app version, clean install for user who was using your app on device A will get shared prefs, local storage etc (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup) to device B upon install of the app. Summing up, if you are using any of the storages mentioned in autobackup url, they will be restored and ready for use.

Comment: The thing is the previous app data is useless at this point, its's the events for last year, the calendar doesn't even show those dates anymore